# How to use domain name instead of local host IP with PHP

Tags: dns, localhost

I'm experimenting some PHP code with a local IP address http://192.168.33.10. 
When I was using the address in a form of number (192.168.33.10) it was working fine (see image 1), but when I try to use a domain name "dev.dotinstall.com", it reaches an error page (see image 2).

I learned that you can use a name like "dev.dotinstall.com" instead of IP address by editing hosts file, so I edited it adding a line "192.168.33.10 dev.dotinstall.com" at the end of the hosts file (see image 3).

The error page says "The fact that you are seeing this page indicates that the website you just visited is either experiencing problems or is undergoing routine maintenance.", but I don't know what the problem is.

Any idea why this is happening?

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: Why `C:\Users\marra\Desktop` ? Should be `hosts` in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggest, Aaron. This was my very first post and didn't know how to edit the "description" of image, and ended up posting the question. Thank you for giving me a more proper tag as well (dns instead of php).

Comment: In the first screenshot, the IP is using port 8000. But the port number is missing from the second screenshot. WIthout the port number, port 80 is usually assumed. Try appending the port number to the domain name and see if that works. dev.dotinstall.com:8000.

Comment: Quasimondo's clone

Yes, it should be located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc, but I couldn't directly open and edit it, so I first dragged it to my desktop and opened it by text editor Atom. After I saved the changed, I relocated to the etc folder. So I assume the hosts file is saved in the correct place.

Comment: dev.dotinstall.com:8000 didn't work. It reached an error page saying "This site can’t be reached dev.dotinstall.com’s server IP address could not be found."

Comment: Wait a minute. I just realized that I hadn't correctly saved the hosts file. I just tried dev.dotinstall.com:8000 again and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you need to add the URL into the hosts file. Make sure you have saved it correctly (with administrator rights) and the port is correct.

This is not enough though, you will need to set up a [virtual host for Apache](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache_vhosts.php) as well and then restart Apache. If you only set the URL in the hosts file, then Apache will not know what to do with it. There are plenty of materials on setting up a virtual host for Apache on Windows if you search for that.

Comment: @ShinichiTakagi you are welcome. If this answers your question, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Well, I meant to ask more, but it was posted when I just pressed the enter button when my post was still incomplete. 

Does this process assume that you have already installed Apache in the first place? I checked my local C: directory, but it seems there is no Apache in it

Comment: @ShinichiTakagi you need a webserver to handle requests. Apache is a possibility. I assumed you were using Apache based on the images you posted in your question. If you install Apache (as part of WAMP, for example), then adding the URL to the hosts file and ensuring that Apache supports virtual host usage, also, ensuring that you have the proper settings for your virtual host URL in the config should solve your issue. I've don this many times in different operating systems successfully.

Comment: When I tried adding a port number 8000 like dev.dotinstall.com:8000, it worked just fine, even though I didn't do anything special with Apache. Though I've solved the problem I originally had, I want to deepen my understanding a little more. What is the thing that you cannot do without Apache? So is it also possible to do the same thing without Apache? For this PHP experiment, I've been using Vagrant, Putty, and CyberDuck. Do these three have anything to do with working as a substitute for Apache?

Comment: @ShinichiTakagi there is nothing you can't do without Apache. Apache is a webserver among many. There are other webservers that you can use with PHP, like IIS, NginX and yes, CyberDuck, which you were using as a server. I have never used CyberDuck as webserver, so I cannot give you an opinion about it, but since it was working for you, you are good to go for now, it is premature to choose webservers, you need to get some first hand experience first to have some ideas to what to look for when searching for webservers.

Comment: @ShinichiTakagi Vagrant is a tool to manage virtual machine environments, in our case dev/server environment, so somebody sets up the server and other people copy that virtual machine, so everybody will be on the same page, at least technically. I have never used Vagrant either, but I used Docker and am using Camps for similar reasons. Putty is an ssh telnet for Windows, you were probably using it to get the environment.

Comment: Ah, okay. So I was using something that could be a substitute for Apache without knowing. The tutorial video that I was watching just instructed to use CyberDuck, Putty and Vagrant, so I just followed it, but just as you mentioned, I will need some experience to be able to tell the difference between different webservers and choose which one meets my demands better.

Comment: @ShinichiTakagi indeed. At this point important is to ensure that you can write some very simple programs and have some initial successes. This is the start of building your programming knowledge. If my answer led you to the right direction, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: I tried to vote for your answer, but it displayed a message like "A user whose point is less than 15 points in reputation cannot change the score", so I did click it but it had no effect, sorry.

Comment: @ShinichiTakagi thank you. Yes, upvoting requires at least 15 reputation points. Accepting an answer by clicking at the checkmark near the vote buttons requires no reputation points, but it is only allowed for the asker of the given question.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean. I've clicked at the checkmark. I also realized that for some reason I was awarded a right to vote a moment ago, so I voted for your answer as well.